# How to properly handle android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Tags: android, video-streaming, screen-orientation

In my app I have to provide the ability to add, move, resize and remove some views, like a launcher does. It worked fine until now, but now I want some of these views to display a video, streamed in real time (like a webcam).

I would like my video not to re-buffer when I change the screen orientation, so I am trying to use the android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" attribute.

It works in most cases but... The problem is that I have to get the new size either when the screen orientation change, or in the onResume function. It is a bit tricky, and it doesn't always work (For example, if I am in landscape mode, and I receive a call, Android automatically switch in portrait mode, and when I come back to my app, it stays in portrait but give me the landscape screen size…).

I have tried to use both addOnLayoutChangeListener and getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener, both failed.

I guess it may be buggy in several other situations, so I thought that the perfect behavior would be to have the normal behavior (eg destroy and re-create my activity in onResume if the orientation changed), and resize my views manually only when the orientation change.

So my questions are :

- Do you think it is a good idea to try do get this behavior ?
- What is the best way to destroy and re-create the activity ? Just calling onDestroy/onCreate  in onResume if the orientation changed ? Or manually set all my pointers to null, and be really careful with memory leaks…

Thank you in advance

Comment: I unfortunately don't have an answer to your question, but _don't even think of calling system lifecycle callbacks manually_. It's a very bad idea to call `onCreate()` in `onResume()`. Also, in an ideal world, you would just pass your player object through `NonConfigurationInstance` calls form the destroyed activity to the newly born one. However, I seem to recall that there may be difficulties doing this for videos.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I already tried to pass the media player through NonConfigurationInstance, but… We are not in an ideal world, and it seems to be impossible with MediaPlayer :/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I recall. It works well with almost everything else, though. ;) Anyway, I'm not sure what your actual question is. What doesn't work for you? -- Regarding many things, it's often thought that they should be done in `onCreate()` when they should really be done in `onResume()`. ;)

Comment: Well it would work if I could get the size of my views in onResume.
At the moment what I have done is to use the android:configChanges, and resize my views in onConfigurationChange function.
The problem is that despite onConfigurationChange is called when I resume to the app (for example after a phone call), the sizes I get are wrong if I changed the orientation while the app was in background. I tried with all the methods I know (onWindowFocusChanged, addOnLayoutChangeListener and getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener), without success :/.

Comment: That's odd. Don't you get an orientation hint then which you could check against the old value? -- All this works flawlessly for me because I just let Android re-create my Activities. The current Activity changes orientation but that's fine and the layout gets adjusted.

Comment: Well I get the right orientation, that's not the problem. The problem is that when I come back to my app (I have the problem only after a phone call, not if I press the home button and come back), if I try to get my views' size, I get the old orientation one.
For example now I am trying with onWindowFocusChanged. If I'm in landscape mode, then I receive a phone call, and come back to the app, the app is in portrait, I ran through onWindowFocusChanged, but the sizes I get there are the landscapes one… Weird.

Comment: Well, after all, in the Manifest, you promised to Android you'd handle it yourself. ;) And do you get a changed orientation info after the phone call, such that you can perform an integrity check on the View size and flip the values if they don't make sense?

Comment: Yes after the phone call both onWindowFocusChanged and onConfigurationChanged are called, but I'd like to avoid to store the portrait and landscape sizes...

Comment: A simple test case is :
- use the configChanges
- override onWindowFocusChanged and print a view's size in it
- put your phone in landscape
- press home
- put your phone in portrait
- come back to your app
- check the logcat : the printed size is the landscape one

I'm going to try getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener inside onWindowFocusChanged…

… It doesn't work.

Comment: Solved it by creating my own layout class and getting the size in onDraw function. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it by creating my own layout class and by getting the size in its onDraw function.
A bit overkill, but it is the only solution I found.

Thanks @Sharad Mhaske and @Class Stacker for your time !

EDIT : I juste realized that I did not mention that I am placing my views inside their container manually, by setting their X and Y position, and their width and height. That's why they do not resized automatically whereas the container does.

EDIT : Here is the piece of code I'm now using :

```
public class TilesContainer extends FrameLayout {

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Public interface for on size change event :
    public static interface OnSizeChangedListener { void onSizeChanged(int width, int height); }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :
    private int _width = -1;
    private int _height = -1;
    private OnSizeChangedListener _listener = null;
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors :
    public TilesContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public TilesContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    public TilesContainer(Context context) {

        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Setters :
    public void setOnSizeChangedListener(OnSizeChangedListener listener) { _listener = listener; }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // onDraw overload :
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Call super :
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // If there is a listener and if the size changed :
        if(_listener != null && (_width != this.getWidth() || _height != this.getHeight()) ) {

            _width = this.getWidth();
            _height = this.getHeight();
            _listener.onSizeChanged(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        }
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Now in the activity, juste implement OnSizeChangedListener, use the setter and add the function :

```
@Override
public void onSizeChanged(int width, int height) {

    // Do your stuff with the GOOD size !
}
```